# How long an essay can be?

Tags: books

I was sure that even the longest essays are about 20-25 pages. But Eric Gill's "An Essay on Typography" is more than 150 pages. And here it becomes unclear to me where is a difference between an essay and a book? How long an essay can be?

Comment: Well, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_on_Typography) calls _An Essay on Typography_ "a book".

Comment: You can write a 1000 page book titled "An Essay on X" where X is something you like to write about.

Comment: A book can have 20-25 pages.

Comment: Merriam-Webster says an essay is "an analytic or interpretative literary composition usually dealing with its subject from a limited or personal point of view". Some other places have 'usually short'. 150 pages is short compared with many other pieces of writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no limit. An essay is only vaguely defined, typically by its focus of topic and length, but there is no hard limit for how short an essay must be to be called an essay. I think most would agree that 150 pages is unusually long for an essay, but still possible. A highly focused persuasive piece of writing could still be called an essay even if very long.

A book is a form factor for a piece of writing, it doesn't describe the type or style of writing itself. Pretty much any piece of writing can be published in book form, whether that's an essay, a novel, technical manual, or biography. "Essay" describes a piece of writing with particular characteristics of purpose, style, and length, while "book" describes a physical object with pages and text.